# Why do some tech companies share their workings on a blog for free

Tags: security

I was reading a blog of how a problem was solved on the Lyft blog here: https://eng.lyft.com/applying-gevent-learnings-to-deliver-value-to-users-part-4-of-4-36ad932deea8

This made me go to their main page: https://eng.lyft.com/ which is a Medium site and I saw a lot of such blogs. I was wondering why would a tech for-profit company share such info besides having to spend time writing it on a site like Medium that too for free? Doesn't this turn into a risk both security wise and competition wise besides the time spent by paid employees putting work on content which will doesn't generate revenue for it.

What am I missing?

Comment: "Doesn't this turn into a risk both security wise and competition wise" – Lyft is an algorithm company. Sharing how they fixed a flickering UI does not in any way expose anything about their algorithms.

Comment: Was asking about the articles on https://eng.lyft.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the HR angle.

Tech companies want to hire "the best" developers. "the best" developers are "the best" because they shout about how great they are on their blog, speak at events, publish open source stuff etc etc.

So you have two options.

1. Hire people who already blog.

   Great, but they will realise that they are valued because they blog and want to continue doing it. They will not accept an offer unless you let them blog about the clever stuff they are doing
2. Turn your existing staff into "the best" devs. This will encourage "run of the mill" developers to come and work for you, because you are "the best" company

   You need to get them to write blogs and present at conferences etc.

If you get them to blog on your website then you can exert control over the content, make sure they don't say anything rude, only dispense generic advice and no companies secrets and make sure it ends with an advert to come and work for you.